# Python: read a text file into a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I really hope you can help me since I'm quite new to Python.

I have a simple text file, without any columns, just rows. Something like this:

```
Bob
Opel
Mike
Ford
Rodger
Renault
Mary
Volkswagen
```

Note that in the text file the names and the cars are without the additional enter. I had to this, otherwise, StackOverflow would project the names next to each other.
The idea is to create a dictionary out of the text file to get a format like this:

```
{[Bob : Opel], [Mike : Ford], [Rodger : Renault], [Mary : Volkswagen]}
```

Can you guys help me out and give an example on how to do this? Would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

you can open a file and iterate through the lines with `readlines`

```
lines, dict = open('file.dat', 'r').readlines(), {}
for i in range(len(lines)/2):
    dict[lines[i*2]] = lines[i*2+1]
print dict
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but why do you need the /2?

Comment: I want to look through half as many sets of lines as there are lines because I'm looking through the lines as pairs.

Comment: Your code gives **3** errors, please edit accordingly. `lines, dict = open('dict.txt', 'r').readlines()/2, {}`
**TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'**

`for i in range(len(lines)/2):`
**TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer**

`{'Mary\n': 'Volkswagen\n', 'Mike\n': 'Ford\n', 'Rodger\n': 'Renault\n', 'Bob\n': 'Opel\n'}`

Comment: @stovfl Sorry about that! I edited my answer and tested it.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as file_:
        dict = {}
        array = list(filter(lambda x: x != '', file_.read().split('\n')))
        for i in range(0, len(array), 2):
                dict[array[i]] = array[i+1]
        print(dict)
```